# Printing from a list to a listbox, pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to print out elements from a list to a listbox using pysimplegui. The problem I am facing is the elements print out with one character on each line instead of the whole element per line.

```py
import string
import subprocess
import winapps
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os.path
import ctypes

file_list_column = [
    [
        sg.Text("File Path"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-File Path-"),
        sg.Button(size=(10, 1), enable_events=True, key="-AddButton-", button_text="Add"),
    ],
    [
        sg.Listbox(
            values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40, 20), key="-File List-"
        )
    ],
    [
        sg.Button(size=(15, 1), enable_events=True, key="-create-", button_text="Create")
    ],
]

layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(file_list_column),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window("Startup Script", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    for x in values:
        if event == "-AddButton-":
            filename = values["-File Path-"]
            values[x] = filename
            window["-File List-"].update(filename)
window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement `window["-File List-"].update(filename)` means `window["-File List-"].update(values=filename)`, it doesn't mean insert one new filename, but replace the whole list of `Listbox` element with a new list `filename` which is a string now, then you go each character in `filename` as one item in the `Listbox` element.

Event loop revised,

```py
file_list = []

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in ("Exit", sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break

    elif event == "-AddButton-":
        new_filename = values["-File Path-"].strip()
        if new_filename not in file_list:
            file_list = sorted(file_list + [new_filename])
            window["-File List-"].update(values=file_list)

window.close()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using sorted?

Comment: Just sorting the list for Listbox element.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. When i input a new string it overwrites the previous input, do you know why this is?

Comment: `When i input a new string it overwrites the previous input` ? Where the previous input is ? in the list ? It won't overwrite the old item in list, just don't add the item already in list.

Comment: From testing, when a new input is put in it puts it in the first position and deletes the previous

Comment: How you put new item to first position ? `file_list[0] = new_filename` means replacement. `file_list.inser(0, new_filename)` means insert new_filename to first position.